# Top queries10 Rac Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need an SQL query that will allow me to retrieve the top 10 based on CPU execution time and the number of executions on an Oracle RAC (Real Application Clusters) that queries all nodes.
Iran this query, but it only returns system queries. However, I need user queries :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET LINESIZE 200
SET PAGESIZE 1000
SET FEEDBACK OFF

-- Top 10 des requêtes basé sur la durée d'exécution
DECLARE
  CURSOR query_cursor IS
    SELECT
      ROWNUM AS rank,
      v.sql_id,
      SUBSTR(v.sql_text, 1, 120) AS truncated_sql,
      TO_CHAR(v.elapsed_time / 1000000, '999999.9') AS elapsed_seconds,
      v.executions
    FROM (
      SELECT
        sql_id,
        sql_text,
        elapsed_time,
        executions
      FROM
        gv$sqlstats
      ORDER BY
        elapsed_time DESC
    ) v
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;

  v_rank NUMBER;
  v_sql_id VARCHAR2(13);
  v_truncated_sql VARCHAR2(120);
  v_elapsed_seconds VARCHAR2(10);
  v_executions NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rank| SQL_ID    |                                        Truncated SQL                                                                    | Elapsed(S)| NbExec');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--|-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------|--------|');

  FOR result IN query_cursor LOOP
    v_rank := result.rank;
    v_sql_id := result.sql_id;
    v_truncated_sql := result.truncated_sql;
    v_elapsed_seconds := result.elapsed_seconds;
    v_executions := result.executions;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      RPAD(TO_CHAR(v_rank),2) || '|' ||
      RPAD(v_sql_id, 13) || '|' ||
      RPAD(v_truncated_sql, 121) || '|' ||
      RPAD(v_elapsed_seconds, 10) || ' |' ||
      RPAD(TO_CHAR(v_executions), 5)|| '   |'
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

| Rank | SQL_ID | Truncated SQL | Elapsed(S) | NbExec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5mw55dp9p6nyt | select nvl(max(al.recid), '0'),nvl(max(al.recid), 0) into :txtparmvalue, :parmvalue from v$archived_log al where | 480931.8 | 81875 |
| 2 | 882k0vh2bdt15 | SELECT NVL(MAX(AL.NEXT_CHANGE#), 0), NVL(MAX(AL.RESETLOGS_CHANGE#), 0) FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG AL, V$DATABASE_INCARNATION DB | 158288.7 | 23165 |
| 3 | 6zq7whdtnf2ru | declare agedFileRec dbms_rcvman.agedFileRec_t; first boolean := FALSE; allde | 134271.1 | 85685 |
| 5 | 6hnhqahphpk8n | select free_mb from v$asm_diskgroup_stat where name=:1 | 117978.8 | 14071 |
| 6 | dqj0vf99v3th5 | SELECT sna.ID, sna.NUMEROSNA, sna.CODECATEGORIESNA, sna.CODETYPESNA, sna.CAMPAGNEDEBUT, sna.CAMPAGNEFIN , sna.SURFACEGR | 111381.5 | 18212 |
| 7 | 6hnhqahphpk8n | select free_mb from v$asm_diskgroup_stat where name=:1 | 109830.5 | 13778 |
| 8 | 6hnhqahphpk8n | select free_mb from v$asm_diskgroup_stat where name=:1 | 109491.1 | 13803 |
| 9 | 6hnhqahphpk8n | select free_mb from v$asm_diskgroup_stat where name=:1 | 100705.2 | 13954 |
| 10 | 4z0v74h1gc1kq | SELECT BS.SET_STAMP LIST_ORDER1, 0 LIST_ORDER2, BS.RECID PKEY, :B9 BACKUP_TYPE, :B9 FILE_TYPE, BS.KEEP KEEP, BS.KEEP_UNT | 88803.0 | 4901 |

Comment: @?/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is simply to generate an AWR report. Logged in locally via sqlplus:

```
@?/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql
```

If you wish to manually query and remove system queries, you should switch to using `gv$sqlarea` and filter out those cursors parsed by `SYS` (though some of those may be generated by DBAs and their scripts):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT sql_id,
               MAX(sql_text) sql_text,
               SUM(elapsed_time)/100 elapsed_time,
               SUM(executions) executions
          FROM gv$sqlarea
         WHERE parsing_schema_name != 'SYS'
         GROUP BY sql_id
         ORDER BY elapsed_time DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

However, such queries are rarely useful. Consider:

1. The statistics in these views are cumulative since cursor load. If the cursor stays in the shared pool for many days because it's often used, the numbers may look quite large but don't actually represent a significant portion of the workload for a particular period of time. It's better to examine a stretch of time, which the AWR report will do, or you can do by querying `dba_hist_sqlstat` and using the deltas.
2. Elapsed time is not necessarily the most useful statistic either. A parallelized query with 32 threads that runs for 1 minute will look like it racked up a half hour of time, whereas it actually used only 1 minute of clock time. If you are interested in how long application activity took to run, this is misleading. And you can't use this as a measure of pressure on the system, because you don't know how much of that elapsed time was concurrency wait (not actually using resources).
3. Top-10 reports can *sometimes* be useful, but rarely so in my experience. A problem query may not show up in the top 10 for a lot of reasons. Similarly, just because something is in the top 10 doesn't mean it's a problem. And the top-10 changes constantly depending on what time range you are looking at. It's far better to look diachronically (across time) than it is to look at a snapshot. To do this, you can run ASH reports or manually query `gv$active_session_history` (recent activity, 1 row per second, or `dba_hist_active_sess_history`, older activity, 1 row per 10 seconds), considering the wait event (`event`) and looking across time. This is best done with graphical tools that can graph data over time. If you have OEM, it uses this data for its graphs. Less helpfully but more easily, one can generate an ASH report (`@?/rdbms/admin/ashrpt.sql`), but this is one again just a snapshot.